# Mobile version allows access to non-committer during closed beta

Tags: bug, status-completed

Following a discussion in the DMZ, we discovered that when using a mobile device, it is possible to access the closed beta - even though I did not commit (or even follow) the proposal.

Of course, this post is itself proof... (pics are too complicated on mobile...)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are correct - the mobile view didn't have the same checks in place as the main login.  This will be fixed in the next build.  For now - enjoy your early access to our private beta all you mobile device lovers!

Comment: Close ALL THE QUESTIONS!

Answer (score 2):

I can confirm this as well. I first registered on Dec 4th UTC on my tablet, but didn't notice until this morning that I was being rejected from a non-mobile browser. Changing the user agent on my desktop browser to that of a mobile allowed me to log in without a problem.

It looks like the code that checks authorization isn't included in the mobile site. Whoops.